# Should an unmarried woman light one or two Shabbat candles?

Tags: shabbat, number, women, candle-lighting

Should an unmarried woman light one or two Shabbat candles? I have seen both practices, but it seems that only little girls light one candle and that a grown-up woman lights two although she is not married. (I light two following the logic of "shamor and zachor".) [I know a married woman lights two.](/q/7605)

Comment: Actually, the common practice is for adults to light at least 2 and 1 for each family member, in total. (I.e. if you have 4 children, you light 6, not 8.)

Comment: One for Shomer and one for zachor,but one is sufficient if one only has that

Comment: Also, a lot of people light an an additional one for any times they missed.

Comment: In very frum communities, it is typical for unmarried women to light one, no matter their age.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common custom is that there is no special duty for a single girl to light Shabbos lights at all. If anyone but the married woman of the house is lighting, the tradition is to light two. Including if a wife isn't home and the husband is lighting. Or your case.

The Lubavitcher rebbe invented the practice of all girls lighting. It hasn't been going on long enough to be qualify as a "minhag", yet. Rabbi JB Soloveitchik advised families that knew their family minhag not to leave their minhag.

As for making a berakhah, for Sepharadim -- the Shulchan Arukh (OC 263:8) would not let someone who is adding light to a room that is already lit make a berakhah. For example, if two families are sharing a dining room, the second person to light shouldn't make a berakhah. So the mother would have to light first, and then the daughter would light without a berakhah. For Ashkenazim -- the Rama disagrees, and allows a berakhah when lighting additional lamps in an already lit room. So, the daughter can make a berakhah in this situation.

(Side note: ideally, one should turn on the electric lights in the dining room as well, so that one is making a berakhah on the lights actually being used for the meal. But because of the above, an Ashkenazi can make a berakhah on the Shabbos candles either way, it's just less than ideal to only make the berakhah on the additional light and not the primary light source.)

Others raised the topic of how many lights should be lit when it's the wife or someone else lighting for an entire household: two, or the minhag of one per person, possibly plus a "fine" of one for each week missed until now.

If you do not know your minhag, I would advocate for just lighting for Shamor and Zakhor. I would like to see the other custom disappear entirely, frankly. I think of the childless wife who passes by the window seeing 8, 9, 13 candles, and feeling pain. Or the mother who lost one of her children, who starts her Shabbos with a sad reminder.

Comment: Thank you very much. I live alone, so no one can do it for me. Plus, my family is secular, so, sadly, minhag is not to light at all... In my community, there is no minhag to light for every child, I think it will never be minhag, and I definitely won't start it once I have children.

Comment: You're welcome. Well then, the answer (as I hope was clear from what I wrote earlier) is that anyone making Shabbos for themselves lights.

If you are invited out for dinner and will be leaving before it's dark enough for the candles to help, you should light at home candles that are long enough to be lit when you get back. Since I don't want to be responsible for burning your house down, maybe light them in the middle of your stovetop?

Comment: I light them in a metal tray, placed on a another tray :D

Comment: actually the minhag of lighting at age three is a much older minhag. It fell out of practice due to hardship and the cost of obtaining candles. The Rebbe merely brought it back. Starting to light at age three is similar to when a young boy gets a haircut and starts wearing kippah and tzitzis. It marking a transition in life of moving from being a baby to being a child.

Answer (score 2):

With candles, their's a large variety of customs, so this is only a partial answer.

> Until marriage, girls light one candle.

http://m.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1221742/jewish/Do-Young-Girls-Light-Shabbat-and-Holiday-Candles.htm

This is from the lubavitcher Rebbe. Unfortunately, I can't find the exact source of the article, but I heard the Rebbe said to do it that way to make a distinction between the lighting of an unmarried person and a married person.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the generally accepted custom outside of Chabad. Ultimately, the actual requirement for both married women and single folk is only to light one, but I think the custom is generally to light two (or more) regardless of your marital status. This all assumes the single person is not living in their parents' home, in which case they don't have to light at all (and I think that is the specific case where Chabad has the additional custom to light one candle, as opposed to zero for non-Chabad).

Comment: In general, see [OC 263](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%A1%D7%92).

Comment: Just to clarify my above comment, I meant "otherwise" instead of "in which case." If you live at home with your parents, you don't have to light candles (except for the Chabad custom to light one anyway, if I recall correctly). If you live on your own, you do.

Comment: @Fred Mainly chabad light candles when the child's able to (like 2 or 3 years old, I'm not sure if the Rebbe spoke about a specific age); although some others do it also. The op even mentioned little girls lighting.

Comment: [Here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15924&st=&pgnum=381&hilite=) is one soure. Elsewhere (I can't find where at the moment, but as I recall) the Rebbe explains that it's to avoid causing offense to the mother who might feel her role is being usurped, and to avoid giving non-religious girls the impression they're lighting a candle for their boyfriend.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the custom for women to light Shabbos candles before marriage and even from a young age, there's a Torah source that this has been practiced since (at least, perhaps even earlier than) our matriarch, Rivkah, as evidenced by her lighting candles before her marriage to Yitzchak.

Source:  https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/project-pls-e0f4f.appspot.com/o/rCtP43u8fcTNzCjxqTeM%2Fpdf%2Fa53bed50-61e0-11ed-b5e8-afbe34788d83?alt=media&token=162333a9-5bdb-4ee4-b06e-5bd837d643fa

Regarding the amount, traditionally, married women light 2 and single women light 1 when they are in a household where other candles are being lit. The actual wording of the law is "It is a mitzvah to light many candles in honor of the Shabbos. Some are accustomed to light ten and others light seven. And in no event should less than two candles be lit symbolizing [the verses:] Zachor [Remember] and Shamor [Preserve]. In time of pressing need even one (candle) is sufficient." - Shulchan Aruch Chapter 75.

https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/4297920/jewish/Chapter-75-The-Laws-of-Candle-Lighting.htm

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Ikay and thanks for this first answer. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: The proof from Rebecca is not helpful. Everyone agrees any Jew needs to light if no one else is. The question is just single girls lighting when someone else already is.